# Css class selector not working (Css Less)

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, less

I have a simple css less class and a hyperlink. But it does not work. can anyone see what the problem is?

```
<a href="xxxxx" class="Phone">
```

The Css less class

```
.Phone{

     display:none;

     @media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px)
     {
       display:inline;
     }
 }
```

Comment: Your CSS is fine -- the problem must be with how your LESS is actually getting compiled to CSS, or the way in which your CSS file gets referenced. Are you using a build system?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Please present all necessary information if you want help.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] otherwise this is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

you didn't close the html :

```
> <a href="url">link text<**/**a>
```